# External URL for CIVIMail on localhost installation

Tags: civimail

I have a locally installed civicrm. Sending mass mails works fine, but as images are stored  locally on the server, recipients cannot see the images nor do click-through-URLs work (as they go over localhost).

Is there any possibility to change the image storage folder to another URL outside the standard civicrm structure (e.g. a website)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is only a partial answer, but the main challenge will be getting files to save to the remote server. Retrieving them will mainly involve adjustments on *Administer > System Settings > Resource URLs*.

If you can get a local folder to sync to a remote file host, that might work well.  Long run, a nice feature would be to have an option to save files directly to S3 or something.

Answer (score 1):

To make images visible you can use images that are not on your local server. Add the url of the image in the image properties.

I've not tried using an external server on the Image Upload URL (Administer > System Settings > Resource URLS), but you could try that too.

Answer (score 0):

That's how I solved it for the moment:
1) Changed the image folder in Administer > System Settings > Resource URLs to a web server address.
2) I made a template with images named 1.jpg, 2.jpg etc. with the URL pointing to the folder on the webserver. When the user wants to insert new images for a mailing, he has to upload the new images named 1.jpg, 2.jpg etc. via ftp to the web server. Not yet very satisfying but at least it works and the user doesn't have to change html code.

Would be great if I could make civicrm upload files via ftp to a webserver.
Also still struggling to find a solution for click-through links when on a local server to get some more statistics.

Answer (score 0):

For image, you can use Amazon S3 (payment require) or other Web Server where you can upload image and get an url to embed

For URL, simply disable Tracking each time you send CIVIMAIL
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can install [CiviProxy](https://docs.civicrm.org/civiproxy/en/latest/) on another server - a free or low-cost VPS should be more than enough.  CiviProxy will cache the images.  It will also ensure that unsubscribe requests, etc. are taken care of.  CiviProxy has a setting to rewrite the URLs of the images to the proxy server.